# How to use a common powershell profile inside a team

Tags: powershell, profile, collaboration

I would like to know how to share and keep up-to-date a profile ($profile.AllUsersAllHosts) beetween all my co-workers.
As i am the only one who make POSH scripts in the team, i'd like to create a sort of framework providing the distribute it to team members.

Is there a way to load profile from an url ? Or should i use the local profil to map a network drive, then load the .ps1 file ?
Other ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than fight the system, I suggest you keep your common profile on a network then have folks dot source that profile within the profile on the machine (either user or machine profile):

```
. \\server\share\CommonProfile.ps1
```

Another option is to create a shortcut to PowerShell.exe with the `-NoExit` parameter that executes the common profile e.g.

```
PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command "& {. \\server\share\CommonProfile.ps1 }"
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, for those who are interrested in here is the complete recipe :

1- On each your co-worker's workstation, modify the profile to dot source the common "profile"

```
-> . \\server\share\commonProfile.ps1
```

2- On the common profile, edit the PSModulePath and add your sharedFolder containing your modules (we test if the shared folder is allready in path)

```
    if($env:PSModulePath -match "\\\\server\\share\\modules" -eq $false){
    $env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";\\server\share\Modules"
}
```

3- Place the modules you create in \\server\share\Modules  and import them from the commonProfile.

Optionaly :

- Use SVN or so to keep your modules folder up-to-date
- Use [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/guide) to track your developpements and bugs
- Auto-generate docs to keep your co-workers aware of what you are doing ( i use a modified version of the [Out-Html script](http://poshcode.org/587) found in poshcode.org

[image]

Finally, Just Relax ;)

Comment: I believe this answer is more thorough.